# Python Add Try Exception in Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following step in my python script that is pulling in every csv file from a directory to then be combined into a single dataframe. I keep on getting errors for a few files in the list (list is about 4000 long) and I'm looking for a way to skip those with errors.

I tried to add a try: except: into this line, but that did not work either. Any ideas?

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(export, l)) for l in os.listdir(export) ])
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
[Finished in 178.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: You're looking for a one-liner code or we can use multiple lines?

Comment: You have to write multi-line for loop which enables you to add try except in it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to build the list item by item, so that you can resume the loop after catching an exception. Something like

```
dataframes = []

for l in os.listdir(export):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(export, l))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        continue
    dataframes.append(df)

combined_csv = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

There is, unfortunately, no *expression* that can catch an exception at this time in Python, only the statement. One was [proposed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/), but rejected.

If you want, you can wrap the `try` statement in a function that return a value you can skip. For example:

```
def make_csv(path):
    try:
        return pd.read_csv(path)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return None

combined_csv = pd.concat([x for x in [make_csv(os.path.join(export, f) for f in os.listdir(export)] if x is not None]
```

or

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([make_csv(os.path.join(export, f)) for f in os.listdir(export)])
```

if you can make `make_csv` return an empty CSV file instead of `None`.